# elementary loki installation stuck at Start the installation

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Elementary Loki through USB. Unfortunately when every i try to install. The Installation stuck at **Start the installation**.
Please Help me

Comment: Please clarify your question. Details of the system, the point at which you are getting stuck (if there are any more details).

Comment: Also have you tried re-formatting the USB?